# I have a Fresh Expo Install trying to import a node_module build fails

Tags: expo, metro-bundler

Here is my metro.config.js file :

```
const extraNodeModules = {
  '@terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas': ('/node_modules/@terrylinla\react-native-sketch-canvas/')
}

const resolverMainFields = ['browser','main'];

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    extraNodeModules,
    resolverMainFields
  },
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

The build worked before I installed the package to node_modules and now I'm getting errors left and right. I got this package working in a react-native app with no expo but I don't know how to get this working with expo.

What am I doing wrong?